C++: How can I parse a function signature from a std::string to call a function from a DLL?
I am trying to make it so that from the script in angel script I can call functions from DLLs.
Now I have written a library class, which has two functions load and unload. What is missing is a call.
Now, to make the picture more complete, let's present the signature of the engine->RegisterObjectMethod() call"
engine->RegisterObjectMethod(“library”, “dictionary@ 
call(const string&in, ?&in=null, ?&in=null, ?&in=null, 
?&in=null, ?&in=null, ?&in=null, ?&in=null, ?&in=null, 
?&in=null, ?&in=null)const", asFUNCTION(library_call), 
asCALL_GENERIC);

The first argument is the function signature expected by the DLL, and the rest are parameters of undefined type.
And that's why I use asIScriptGeneric! To loop through the argument list and call the function, but to call it correctly, I need to return type and convert the function arguments to the correct types, as well as allocate memory for pointers if the signature is int* for example.
Finally, I want to call the function and pass to the CScriptDictionary under the key 0, what the function returned, and from one to ten, the pointer variables, if there are any.
void library_call(asIScriptGeneric* gen) {
#undef GetObject//For WinAPI
        asIScriptContext* ctx = asGetActiveContext();
        library* lib_obj = (library*)gen->GetObject();

        void* ref = gen->GetArgAddress(0);
        typedef void* (*func)(...);
        std::string func_name= *static_cast<string*>(ref);
        //Function signature parser:
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;
        std::string token;
        for (char c : func_name) {
            if (c == ' ' || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == ',' || c == ';') {
                if (!token.empty()) {
                    tokens.push_back(token);
                    token.clear();
                }
            }
            else {
                token += c;
            }
        }

        // First array: Return type and function name
        std::vector<std::string> first;
        first.push_back(tokens[0]);  // Return type
        first.push_back(tokens[1]);  // Function name

        // Second array: Parameters
        std::vector<std::string> last;
        for (size_t i = 2; i < tokens.size(); ++i) {
            if (!tokens[i].empty()) {
                last.push_back(tokens[i]);
            }
        }

        FARPROC address = GetProcAddress(lib_obj->lib, first[1].c_str());
        if (address == NULL) {
            const char* name = first[1].c_str();
            std::string message = "Signature parse error: GetProcAddress failed for '" + std::string(name) + "'";
            ctx->SetException(message.c_str());
            return;
        }
        func function = reinterpret_cast<func>(address);

How to convert arguments to the required types and allocate memory for pointers, if any?

If there is a small number of variations on the possible parameters you could have if or case statements to handle the different function signatures. One for DWORD func (int, wchar_t*, wchar_t*, int), one for DWORD foo2 (int); ... -- this will not scale up very well.

It isn't clear why you need to parse the signature. Please show how you would use the parsing function (just assume that it exists). If you need to extract just the function name I can understand that. Can you show an example string you want to parse?

C++ is a compiled language, not a scripting language. You can't build up a function call dynamically from a string and then execute it like you have described (well, you can, but it is not trivial, requiring you to place manually crafted CPU instructions into a block of executable memory - this is definitely not something that is covered by the C++ language itself).

@RemyLebeau AngelScript does. It has a lot of macro magic that calls registering functions and while it has some internal indexing, the friendly way to query or execute them is to use their signature. Unfortunately he didn't tag it with the angelscript tag so it seems he wants to do C++ stuff from C++, when in reality, he means to call native functions from a scripting VM. I still see no reason why the OS window handle needs to be sent, nor why you would give OS-specific function access to a game, but I got used to crazy and hacky ideas for game workflows posted here as proper use-cases.

@n.m.couldbeanAI That's how AngelScript does it. The question is more about how AS does what it does, rather than how C++ does it. The confusion between the two makes me think he is a beginner which is why the idea in the question is so strange (creating an OS-controlled window from a script designed for games). Signatures are the way AS identifies functions uniquely (including overloaded ones) and finds their stored typedef pointers.

What is dictionary? What are the in parameters, what is the call inside the parameters? It is still not clear what you're trying to achieve. As I said before: if you define a function in a way AS can use it and if you register a function properly, then you can call it from the script. There is nothing more beyond that. There is no need for any parsing of argument types, converting from signature string to typedef and so on. Since you want to modify the framework's behavior, you should implement your own interfaces (not modify existing ones, mind you, but you can use them as a base).

And as said before, you are not using asIScriptGeneric. Unless you actually wrote code in it which I doubt, since it would break the script framework. The fact you're using code asIScriptGeneric* script; script->Whatever(); does not mean what you think it means. Trust me, you're not using asIScriptGeneric and you insisting that you use it tells me you need to study on C++ more before you attempt whatever it is you are trying. Skipping lessons is not a good idea, especially on such a complex language as C++.


How can I acquire, for example, from a string?

You don't. AngelScript binds predetermined functions, meaning you need to register MessageBoxW before using it. AngelScript doesn't magically call any function in the world based on a signature. It needs to know about it beforehand.
r = engine->RegisterGlobalFunction("int MessageBoxW(int, wchar_t*, wchar_t*, int);", asFUNCTIONPR(MessageBoxW, (int, wchar_t*, wchar_t*), int), asCALL_CDECL); 

Because wchar_t is a special case of it being used as a string as opposed to being a string, the above might be a wrong approach and you'll need a wrapper that uses asCString (if I remember correctly - sorry, been some time since I tested AngelScript) or ::std::wstring. This is, of course, assuming you built it with UNICODE.
This might be closer to what you need, but as said, you'll need to re-read the docs and adapt it properly:
#include <string>

int MyMessageBox(::std::wstring Text, ::std::wstring Caption)
{
     MessageBoxW(g_hWnd, Text, Caption);
}

r = engine->RegisterGlobalFunction("int MyMessageBox(string, string, int);", asFUNCTIONPR(MyMessageBox, (wstring, wstring), int), asCALL_CDECL); 

Notice I didn't include the window handle. Why? Well, why would you expose OS-specific stuff to a script inside a game? Scripts run inside a sandbox and there's a reason for that. You need to cache the windows (which should be the game itself anyway) and just use it inside the wrapper.
If you don't use UNICODE, of course you'd use ::std::string and MessageBoxA().
As for the typedef, you can pass it to asFUNCTIONPR(). I recommend you don't name it identically to the function name itself, maybe prefix it with t: tMyMessageBox()

Now I will try to explain in more detail what I need. I'm using asIScriptGeneric to iterate over the arguments.
I have a tokenizer that will split a string into two arrays. str[0] is the return type, str[1] is the function name, the rest are the argument types.
It may not be a typedef, but I need to convert each argument to the required type for the call, and also allocate memory for pointers, if any.
Using asIScriptGeneric::GetArgAddress();, I get the address of the argument, and all I have to do is cast it to the desired type and call the function.

Let's clarify: you're most likely using the default one, not asIScriptGeneric. You can't use asIScriptGeneric. "and also allocate memory for pointers, if any" What pointers? Are you talking about the string signature? Or the pointer values of arguments? Also, that's not what GetArgAddress() is for. Please explain what your use-case is properly, because it sounds like an XY Problem. Are you trying to call the functions from the script VM or from C++? Why do you need a message box? Why do you need its window handle? What's the objective?

I modified my question a little by adding lines of code there.
Also, I'm not going to call the MessageBox function from the game engine, I just want to write a call function and make sure that the functions are actually called from the DLL.
